# Laplace transformation of a piecewise function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How to find Laplace transformation of
$$
f(t) =
\begin{cases}
1, & t\geq 0, t\neq 1, t\neq 2 \\
3, & t=1 \\
4, & t=2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Please, show your efforts! :D

Comment: I need some hint

Comment: It's an integral transform, and integrals don't change just because you modify a finite number of values of the integrand ...

Comment: Use the definition of laplace transforms and start taking integrals

Comment: May this question be wrong?

Comment: Don't you mean $1>t>2$ instead of $t =1$? Otherwise it's simply laplace of  1.

Comment: I know I need to take integral but the function changes only one point and I stuck

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be as stated in the question and let $\hat{f}(x)$ differ from $f(x)$ in finitely many points. Then:

$\int\limits_a^b f(x) dx = \int\limits_a^b \hat{f}(x) dx$ for all $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$.

This should help you.
Take $\hat{f}(x) =1$ then we have $f(x) = \hat{f}(x)$ except for $x = 1,2$ which is a finite amount.